# Pi 4 thinks I have 2 displays?

Tags: hdmi, display, raspbian-buster

I'm sure there is a better way to ask this, so I apologize in advance!

My Pi 4 seems convinced I have 2 displays connected. I can change the resolution for HDMI-1 and HDMI-2, despite just having 1 monitor connected. This wouldn't be an issue except I can't maximize a window - it will only maximize to the size of that "phantom" HDMI-1. Does this make sense? I think I am trying to ask how I can configure things so that when I modify resolution or other display settings, it's only for the 1 display that's actually connected?

Comment: Presumably you have used the secondary HDMI port - use the port nearest power

Comment: This is fantastic - thank you! I had no idea that primary / secondary applied - I thought I had 2, and they could be used at will. Could you link me to something that explains why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

`Start button` > `Preferences` > `Display Settings`

(If `Display settings` is not there:

`Start button` > `Preferences` > `Main Menu Editor` add `Display Settings` to the `Preferences` menu)

Otherwise launch the same `Display settings` by writing `lxrandr` in terminal.

In `Display Settings` you have checkboxes where you can enable/disable the HDMI ports/screens.

[image]